# RxJS - construct objects with properties being resolved asynchronously

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, asynchronous, rxjs

I have json file with the following content:

```
"brushPresets":
[
{
  "name": "fur",
  "imageUrl": "brush.png",
  "func": "spray",
  "scale": "1"
},
{
  "name": "tinsel",
  "imageUrl": "brush.png",
  "func": "fur",
  "scale": "1"
}, ....]
```

I need to construct an array of BrushPreset objects that have the following properties:

```
name:string,
image:HTMLImageElement,
func:Function,
scale:number
```

Thus, I need to load a json file first and then for each brush load an image asynchronously and assign it to the image property of the BrushPreset object.

The loadImage(url:string) method is already implemented and returns Observable< HtmlImageElement >.

How would I implement the method that loads this json file and returns

```
Observable< BrushPreset[]>
```

Comment: Please review the guideline https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. As currently expressed, your question is too broad and does not show any sign of research or attempt at solving the problem. You can also review https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Excuse me. How was I supposed to show that I was trying to solve this problem if none of my attempts were successful? I was looking at mergeMap, concatMap, forkJoin. But didn't manage to find the right combination of the operators to solve the problem. And only confused myself. Thus, I tried to state the problem as clear as I can without the attempts that didn't work.

Comment: If one of your attempts were successful, then you would not have a problem. Such is the case for the vast majority of people posting questions. However, it is a recommended practice to show the research that you have made (see guideline), the problems that you have encountered and not solved. That in many cases involves showing some of the code you tried but did not work. Second, as your question is expressed, it is too broad : load a json file,  load an image etc. Each one of these could be questions on their own (how do I load a file?).

Comment: I particularly recommend you to have a look at other questions on SO, as whatever problem you have has probably been experienced by somebody else and has a related question with answer on SO from which you often can derive at least a partial solution.

Comment: It's not the first question I asked. And I do understand how the system works here.
 -> Each one of these could be questions on their own (how do I load a file?).

The question that I'm interested in is emphasized in the end. Other parts are clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I managed to solve the problem.
The answer was to combine concatMap with forkJoin like following:

Here's the code as it is in the project:

```
this.presets$ =
      this.http.get('./assets/brushes/brushes.json')
          .map((res:Response) => res.json()["brushPresets"])
          .concatMap(objAr =>
              Observable.forkJoin(objAr.map(obj =>
                  this.loadImage(obj["image"])
                      .map(image => {
                        return new BrushPreset(obj["name"], image, BRUSH_FUNCTIONS[item["func"]], obj["scale"]);
                      })
                  )
              )
          );
```

Edit:

Here's an alternative solution.

```
this.presets$ =
      this.http.get('./assets/brushes/brushes.json')
          .map((res:Response) => res.json()["brushPresets"])
          .mergeMap(this.loadImage, (item, image) => {
            return new BrushPreset(
                item["name"],
                image,
                BRUSH_FUNCTIONS[item["func"]],
                item["scale"]);
          })
          .toArray()
```